# How to close group menu in NavigationView with Expandable

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, expandablelistview, navigationview, android-navigationview

I have a `NavigationView`. I used a `ExpandableListView` for create a `subMenu` in my `NavigationView`.Now i have a problem with `subMenu` in the `NavigationView`.My problem is i don't know how to close `subMenu` after open this because when i close `NavigationMenu` and open it again `subMenu` is still open.`

I didn't know what to write about this problem on Google because my english is not good.

My way is like this [enter link description here](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Comment: post some code !

Comment: you can see now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    if(navigationView.isDraweOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
    expandableListView.collapseGroup(i);
       }
```